Unable to synchronize
I'm using polkadot-stable2409-1.
Blocks have become out of sync since around 2024-11-22 22:14:24
polkadot-sdk has logs like the following
2024-11-22 22:14:24 ❌ Error while dialing /dns/telemetry.polkadot.io/tcp/443/x-parity-wss/%2Fsubmit%2F: Custom { kind: Other, error: Other(Left(Handshake("server rejected handshake; status code = 502"))) }    

After restarting the node, the following log was output
2024-11-23 00:09:26  Error importing block 0xa7d3b66e0d8194ed4dbeb570e22b1dd67e2ddbcb0a0e91829ef72c2cb686d7f5: block has an unknown parent

I think the network is unstable.
what is happening?
